# Google store's new policies with mining apps

Tags: google-play, policy

I have a mining app on the google store, but it doesn't run any actual mining scripts on the user's devices, it just rewards the users and monetizes itself through ads, does that poses a problem with the latest google's policy prohibiting mining apps ?

Comment: StackOverflow is the wrong forum for Policy questions. Looking at the Developer Policy Center is usually the best approach. https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is the wrong forum for Policy questions.